# Ubuntu on VirtualBox leads to a black screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, virtualbox

After VirtualBox boot, I see a regular Ubuntu menu from the official OS image:

[image]

But it doesn't matter what I choose from here. Choosing anything will lead to a black screen with blinking cursor.

[image]

I am trying to install [Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop (32-bit)](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) since without virtualization x64 version isn't possible to install. I am on the latest fresh version of VirtualBox 5.2.

Is there anything I can do?

---

Here I choose nomodeset, then I press esc to close that window and press enter to proceed with the installation. After that I am back to black screen. 
[image]

Comment: Press F6 and edit out the "quiet splash" from the line that appears at the bottom.  Then press enter. This will show you all the messages generated during boot and may give you an idea of where it's getting stuck.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the reply. I just tried and deleted "quiet splash" from the boot options and nothing changed. I also downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Choose F6 and then select nomodeset and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I saw that advice on one of the forums I visited. Still don't know what that is, but nothing changed after I click on it.

Comment: If I recall, you ARROW key down to nomodeset, then hit SPACE BAR to select it, then continue with whatever key.

Comment: @heynnema I am not sure what could go wrong, I added another screenshot at the bottom of the question.

Comment: This may/may not make a difference... instead of hitting ESC (which may clear the highlighted item) to close the F6 popup window, try clicking outside of the window,  or clicking on F6 again, then choose TRY UBUNTU.

Comment: @heynnema I mean if I press the F6 and open that window again it shows the option still being checked. I have no cursor in that state as well as clicking F6 twice doesn't do anything. So I guess the option is checked but nothing happens for some reason :/ (oh and I tried all the options in that menu already, all of them lead to a black screen)

Comment: What are your CPU and MEM settings for the VM? When you first set up the VM, which Linux/Ubuntu choice did you make?

Comment: @heynnema First choice was Linux/Ubuntu x32. 25 Gb of storage, 3 Gigs of RAM. I am not sure about processor. In system-processor it says one processor with 100% execution cap. Also, 16 Mbs of Video memory if that matters at all.

Comment: Hum... it doesn't sound that far off. Try CPU count =2, MEM = 2048, NETWORK = bridged, and TRY UBUNTU.

Comment: @heynnema it says I need hardware virtualization support to change the number of processors. 2 Gb or ram and bridged adapter also did not work. And it is Ubuntu: type: Linux, version: Ubuntu (32 bit).

Comment: Check your BIOS settings and see if there's a setting... something like VTx... for hardware virtualization support.

Comment: @heynnema I mean even if there is then why 14.04 works fine? That's just weird for me.

Comment: I guess that I don't have a solution for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but since this gained traction my solution was rather a workaround. I never found any other information about this and have not resolved the issue.

What worked for me is to use 14.04 version instead of 16 and that's where it ended. I am not sure if it's the Ubuntu bug, or virtualbox bug or a brainfart I caught but I hope there won't be any issues with future versions of Ubuntu on this.

Answer (score 2):

@ OP -

Have you checked your BIOS of the host machine to enable virtualization technology?   I had the same issue.  I took notice when I could only install 32-bit systems even though I run a 64-bit environment.  If you can, get to the BIOS, enable the Virtualization Technology (Intel VT or AMD-V) and then try again.   I did the above step and I am running the install with no problems and I have the option now to select 32-bit or 64-bit installs.

Cheers.